# Open session of Facebook, on token without a window (web dialog) authorization

Tags: android, facebook, session, dialog, facebook-access-token

Prompt how to correctly use the method `openActiveSessionWithAccessToken()` in Fasebook API. Authorization pass, get token, and launch a dialogue posting, it appears (I can post). After cleaning token, and a closed session, the method of `closeAndClearTokenInformation()` I'm trying to open a session already having previously received the token, and the session is opened, there is a dialogue, but alas, writes that an error occurred try again later.

In the dialog box displays: 
An error occurred. Please try again later.

and gives an error in the log: 
Error Code 110, 
Error Description: Invalid user id, 
Error Message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user).

Here's the code:

```
public static void migrateFbTokenToSession() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(getAccessToken(), new Date(getAccessExpires()), null, AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NATIVE, Arrays.asList(Constants.FB_APP_PERMISSIONS));
    Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(getContext(), accessToken , new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                       if(session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removed preous session so how will you get access. You need to login again. If you want to maintain session then just use **UiLifecycleHelper** .

Comment: You are removed preous session so how will you get access. You need to login again. If you want to maintain session then just use UiLifecycleHelper.



The idea is that I can not keep only one session. If the user has passed the authorization once, the next times I did not have to show him the authorization window. This is due to the fact that the application is multi-user and at the same time send a record on the wall can each user, if I remember the session for a single user, the other user will not be able to to send a record to the wall, as his session will not be disclosed.

Comment: So clear token information . and call openactive session for new user.

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
  session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

Comment: But in this way for a new user login window appears. But I kept the earlier token for each user that has passed authentication, through dialog and now just want to target user open a session in order to the user again, did not enter your details (e-mail and password).

Comment: i dont think so this is possible. cause each user has its own session.

Comment: But why then need a method openActiveSessionWithAccessToken() ? On ios possible, I do not think that android is not real.

Comment: May be because facebook documentation also not so clear. But as per me need to call open active session cause saame thing i worked , and dont have time for search so direct called open actve session

Comment: Maybe you know where the documentation Facebook, says that you can not open a session only token?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with using createFromString method like this:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromString(savedTokenAsString, facebookPermissions, AccessTokenSource.NONE); 
    Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(context, accessToken, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) { }
    });
```

But you need to make createFromString method **public**, because its **package-private** in facebook sdk.